# How to set multi-language in Google Apps Marketplace SDK?

Tags: marketplace, google-apps-marketplace

As you see below, I want set multi-language for my app ! Could you show me any idea ?

[image google app marketplace](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3JdgWfkD38ZQXh4ejhTNUlOWk0/edit)

Thank very much !!!

Answer (score 1):

The Marketplace currently does not support localized listings. That is a feature we would like to add in the future but we do not have an ETA.